# Could "COVID-19" be the name of the beast? (Rev 13:18)

Tags: eschatology, revelation, numerology, 666, disease

Greetings to the Community. I come seeking advice from those who currently have much more knowledge about theology than probably I will ever have.

Yesterday morning I did this with pencil and paper:

```
C   =>   100 +
0   =>     0
V   =>     5
I   =>     1
D   =>   500

1   =>     1
9   =>     9
        _____
Total:   616
```

It was a simple sum, came out on the first try. I confess that right after doing it I was a little scared by how easy it was (and of course the meaning it has). I mean, occasionally I've come across articles where complicated mathematical operations are performed to reach certain conclusions. This was not the case.

The points that I am handling so far:

#### The number the beast is not a number in itself but a product of its name:

> **Revelation 13:17:** so that no one can buy or sell who does not have the mark, that is, the name of the beast or the number of its name.
>
> ([Source](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2013%3A17&version=NRSV))

#### The dialectic around the number 616:

> The new number 616 isn’t new, it’s old, that’s the point. It isn’t one
> man’s opinion either, it’s written as such in the two oldest known
> versions of the Bible. The [Oxyrhynchus papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_115) you mention, but
> it’s written too in the [Codex Ephraemi Rescriptus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codex_Ephraemi_Rescriptus), both as a
> number and text - ‘hexakosiai deka hex’ literally translated as six
> hundred and sixteen. This latter book is the last of the four uncial
> manuscripts of the Greek Bible named after Ephraem the Syrian.
>
> ([Source](https://escapeallthesethings.com/666-616-number-mark-of-the-beast#comment-1922))

My questions are:

- Could "COVID-19" be the name of the beast?
- Assuming for a second that the above is true: would the set of facts related to coronavirus pandemic (COVID-19) faithfully correspond to the behavior and actions of the beast, described in detail throughout the book Revelations?

Comment: The translations I use have the number of the Beast as 666, not 616.

Comment: There is a textual issue in this part of Rev. Both 616 and 666 are witnessed to as readings, but the mere presence of readings, or their number, or even their earliness, is not an indicator of authenticity, as the texts are not coming to us in one way, or from one stream, or one region, or one generation, etc. Some have posited that depending on who or what the church transmitting this particular verse thought the beast was influenced the numeral, for example. Also, Revelation uses, virtually exclusively, symbolic language, where the vision is being described, not what the vision depicts.

Comment: I found this article [Ante-Nicene Fathers on the Number of the Beast](http://www.spiritandtruth.org/questions/229.htm?x=x) to be worthy of reading to temper modern day speculation.

Comment: [This article](https://americanvision.org/10369/calculating-the-number-of-the-beast/) makes a case for assigning it to Nero as well as the necessity to consider how John thinks in Hebrew, so the letters need to be transliterated into Hebrew first.  Looks like Paul Chernoch had the same idea :-).

Comment: COVID-19 seems to serve only as an instrument for the acceptance of RFID chips in the forehead or hand.  The reason is, a paper money or a debit/credit card can be a source of transmitting the virus if the one who handle it was infected. The future of "buy & sell" in the Book of Revelation speak of a cashless transaction and everyone must accept a mark if they want access to foods & goods which the Beast who received the authority from the Dragon has the control.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs If you want to ask about some other connection between Covid-19 and Revelation, you'll need to do that in another question. This one is clearly about numerology and the name of the beast.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs Here in Canada, tapping your card on the payment device (via NFC) is quite the norm.  There is no handing of your card to a person, and you don't have to press anything.  This is much more feasible going trend than embedding RFID chip in the forehead !

Comment: (1/2) Sorry curiousdannii but at the end of the post I made one question, then another one directly related to the first one. @itzsophia'svlogs' gave a valid comment that answers directly that second question. On the other hand, this user suggested a better modification of the title which describes the content even better, an edition which I approved. After that you have been reverted the changes directly.

Comment: (2/2) Not to mention that such action is an act of rudeness, the important part is that (going into context) it was a wrong action, as a result of you did not read the content well (by saying that "This one is clearly about numerology and the name of the beast" means that you missed the second question). Although I am an old Stack Exchange user, I am a new user in Christianity. Out of respect for your brilliant career in this space and to avoid falling into unnecessary controversy, I won't restore the changes. However this goes with a suggestion: in the future read well before editing. Regards

Comment: @DarioFerrer When you have two sub-questions it's the title that shows what the main one is, as does the fact that it's 80% of the content of your question. And actually itzsophia'svlogs's alternative title wasn't related to *either* sub- question! And they edited the first sub-question to something else entirely as well as changing the title. There is no "evil instrument" in Revelation, nor your question. That's foreign language to the whole issue. It could be explained in an answer, but it does not belong in the question.

Comment: But sorry if it felt like your toes were being stepped on. I truly don't think it was an appropriate edit. If it had left the first sub-question alone, then maybe, but it didn't. Because I did read the content carefully.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I agree, but the question cited Revelation13:17, and RFID seems to be directly connected to a scenario, wherein people who accept a RFID are the only one who can have access to "buy & sell", but this prophecy need to have a scenario wherein "cash & card" need to be eliminated as control measures in the near future. COVID-19 seems to be the instrument as a prelude to Rev13:17.

Comment: According to what you say, coronavirus could be the perfect excuse to finally implement such a control system on a mandatory basis. Those who refuse to use it could be penalized since they would be illegally out of the system (like those who do not currently have a driver's license). It looks like something that could happen in the immediate future. I had not thought of it. Good approach.

Comment: @DarioFerrer Your main problem is 666 - the number six often relating to man (in Adam, short of perfect seven) and the triple representation agreeing with Thessalonians 2:4. Humanity exalted into the place of Deity within the context of worship. 616 doesn't mean anything spiritually and the codices containing it are suspect from other evidences of content. The result of Covid-19 is reduction of greenhouse gases and a cleaner atmosphere with comparatively little loss of life (comparatively). A necessary, corrective measure ? The rich and powerful will take advantage, but then they always do.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs 1/2 A few decades ago it's 666 in barcodes that was the rage (good technical description of how it's embedded in the now ubiquitous UPC code  [here](https://endtimestruth.com/666-2/barcode-technology-666/) but do systems in place is meant **to oppress or liberate**?  Do governments prohibit eBay that uses PayPal that in turn uses credit card, or Craigslist that trade goods with UPC with cash?

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs 2/2 I think the evil is not in technology but more of the powerful oppressing the weak, same theme that the OT prophets have been rebuking Israel more than 2,500 years ago.  Looking at 666 in technology itself is misguided, but look at government like China which uses technology for censorship and for restricting free speech instead.  Like the opponents of gun control say: it's the person behind the trigger that is the problem, not the gun itself.

Answer (score 2):

The use of letters that form a word or phrase to represent numbers depends upon the language and alphabet used. Saint John would have written Revelation in Greek (or possibly Hebrew), not Latin. Thus Roman numerals are not what you should use. To make your point, you need to use the Greek Alphabet and the Greek translation of COVID-19.

Comment: In addition, COVID-19 is an _acronym_ of the _english_ phrase "corona virus disease 2019", which then is being interpreted as roman numerals. And it's not even interpretting the roman numerals correctly, as you ignore the dash, and have to interpret the letter O as the number zero, which I'm not certain even existed in roman numerals...

Comment: While I agree that COVID-19 has nothing to do with the mark of the beast and the number of its name, I don't agree that you shouldn't use Roman numerals just because it wasn't written in the original language. This was told to John by the angel in Greek, but that doesn't mean it is restricted to use only in Greek.